# How to remove jre1.8.0.72?

Tags: apt, uninstall, purge

There is an error during install jre1.8.0.72. How should I remove it? I get an error during purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge jre1.8.0-72


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jre1.8.0-72
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 26 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 126 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 454719 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jre1.8.0-72 ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-72.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing jre1.8.0-72 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-72
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you remember how you installed Java in the first place?

Comment: I just use the sudo dpkg -i jre1.8.0-72.deb to install.

Comment: Where did you download it from?

Comment: download from here:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Its good that you solved your issue, but there aren't any `*.deb` files in the link you redirected to. Are you sure you installed it in that way?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Java using [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) script, then to uninstall Java do the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge oracle-java8-installer
```

If you installed Java from Ubuntu repositories, then you can remove it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-*
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I solved my problem through create a empty file "/usr/sbin/alternatives"

Comment: Nice! that you solved your own question. Post your answer and accept it.

Comment: Will post it tomorrow morning (very late now)

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall the existing Java , you can execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-8-jre-lib
```

To install the Java V8 again,

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score -1):

This error `/usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory` can be solved to create a empty file.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)